# Extracting text from hyperlink using XPath

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I am using Python along with Xpath to scrape Reddit. Currently I am working on the front page. I am trying to extract links from its front page and display their titles in the shell.

For this I am using the Scrapy framework. I am testing this in the Scrapy shell itself.

My question is this: How do I extract the text from the `<a> ABC </a>` attribute. I want the string "ABC". I cannot find it. I have tried the following expressions, but it does not seem to work.

`response.xpath('//p[descendant::a[contains(@class,"title")]]/@value')`

`response.xpath('//p[descendant::a[contains(@class,"title")]]/@data')`

`response.xpath('//p[descendant::a[contains(@class,"title")]]').extract()`

`response.xpath('//p[descendant::a[contains(@class,"title")]]/text()')`

None of them seem to work. When I use `extract()`, it gives me the whole attribute itself. For example, instead of giving me `ABC`, it will give me `<a>ABC</a>`.

How can i extract the text string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `<p>` and `<a>` are in this situation:

```
<p>
    <something>
        <a class="title">ABC</a>
    </something>
</p>
```

This will give you "ABC":

```
>>print response.xpath('//p//a[@class="title"]/text()').extract()[0]
ABC
```

`//` is equal of using `descendants`. `p[descendant::a]` wont give you the result because you are not considering `<a>` as descendant of `<p>`

Comment: That was the mistake I was making!

Answer (score 1):

Only tested it with online XPath evaluator, but it should work when you adjust it to

```
response.xpath('//p/descendant::a[contains(@class,"title")]/text()')
```

If you're evaluating `//p[descendant::a[contains(@class,"title")]]/text()`, the `<p>` (with the descendant `<a>`) is the current element and not the `<a>`.

Comment: didn't you miss `'` in your `.xpath()` function. because like this you will have a syntax error.

Comment: @NimaSoroush Thanks for mentioning; for the answer I've adjusted the `.xpath()` from the OP and only tested the xpath expression, not the function. Just corrected that.